# К какой фигуре речи относится выражение "Душа компании"?

Tags: фигуры-речи

Поясните, пожалуйста. Муж утверждает, что это оксюморон, но я с ним не согласна.

Answer (score 2):

Это метафора - переносное значение слова, скрытое сравнение.

В прямом значении **душа** - внутренний мир человека, психические переживания как основа его жизни.

В переносном - главное лицо где-либо, организатор, вдохновитель, общий любимец в коллективе.

***Душа компании - общий любимец компании, вдохновитель.*** Здесь скрытое сравнение: душа человека -  основа жизни человека, а душа компании - основа жизни (существования, деятельности) компании (хоть компании друзей, хоть компании как предприятия).

Можно назвать и **фразеологизмом на основе метафоры**, потому что это выражение стало поговоркой, заменяет слово "любимец", или "вдохновитель", или "весельчак", смотря какой смысл вкладывается.

Comment: Воспользуюсь Вашим ответом (я его поддержал) для своего комментария. Возможно, муж и жена имеют в виду разные значения слова "компания". Я пробую на вкус выражение "душа фирмы", и мне оно как-то тоже не очень :)

Comment: Или значение слова "душа" -  в значении "весельчак, вдохновитель" или в значении "вдохновение, искренность", как в паре "он мозг фирмы, а она - душа фирмы".

Answer (score 1):

Эта фразеологизм.     Душа компании - 
    тот, кто развлекает, является центром компании, общества, заводила.

ОКСЮМОРОН (греч. — «острая глупость») — термин античной стилистики, обозначающий нарочитое сочетание противоречивых понятий. Пример: «Смотри, ей **весело грустит**ь/ **Такой нарядно-обнаженной»** (Ахматова). Частный случай О. образует фигура contradictio in adjecto, — соединение существительного с контрастным по смыслу прилагательным: **«убогая роскошь» (Некрасов).**
Ср.: также названия известных фильмов: **Правдивая ложь, Обыкновенное чудо, С широко закрытами глазами и т. д.**

Answer (score 0):

Муж перебарщивает. Душа компании - это заводила, магнит, настройщик настроения, а не придурок, от поступок которого люди восхищаются непредвиденностью.

Comment: Вопрос о «фигуре речи». Не о синониме.

Comment: Ответил на половину вопроса, что "душа компании" не стоит причислять к оксюморону.